# Use nth-child on parent level only

Tags: css

I am trying to target all top level `.dokan-form-group` elements with nth-child.

As you can see, there is a wrapper in the middle called `dokan-child-wrapper` which has some `dokan-form-group` elements inside.

I don't want to target these. Only the upper most top level classes which match dokan-form-group, which is a direct descendant of `.wrapper`.

You can see it's targeting 4 items, but the 3rd and 4th are targeting the child elements which I don't want.

[image]

**Code example:**

https://codepen.io/jordanc26/pen/NWKOXKQ

**HTML / SCSS Code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="dokan-form-group">parent-item</div>
  <div class="dokan-form-group">parent-item</div>

  <div class="dokan-child-wrapper">
    <div class="dokan-form-group">child-item</div>
    <div class="dokan-form-group">child-item</div>
    <div class="dokan-form-group">child-item</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dokan-form-group">parent-item</div>
  <div class="dokan-form-group">parent-item</div>

</div>
```

.

```
.wrapper {

  .dokan-form-group {
    background-color: blue;

    &:nth-child(0),
    &:nth-child(1),
    &:nth-child(2),
    &:nth-child(3) {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried direct child selector `>`? `.wrapper > .dokan-form-group { background-color: red; }` will only target the direct decendants of `.wrapper`.

Comment: I need to do that in conjunction to nth-child too. `.wrapper > &:nth-child(1), &nth-child(4)` etc. Once it's targeting parent levels only, I need to target specific top level, that's why I also have nth-child going on. I tried `> &:nth-child(3) {` and so far nothing.

Comment: Looks like you are using sass, just add `>` to the `.dokan-form-group` selector like this: `> .dokan-form-group { ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change scss to:

```
.wrapper {

  >.dokan-form-group {
    background-color: blue;

    &:nth-child(1),
    &:nth-child(2),
    &:nth-child(3),
    &:nth-child(4) {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }

}
```

[live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g07mk263/)

Comment: As you can see in my and your demo's, the last 2 items are still blue, meaning the nth-child(2), nth-child(3) is not taking effect.

Comment: All nth-child elements should be red.

Comment: @wharfdale so you want to target first 4 children of `wrapper` with class `dokan-form-group`?

Comment: yes. See the codepen demo, all dokan-form-group items immediately below the wrapper parent should be red.

Comment: Because I have an element which is not dokan-form-group between the 3rd and 4th dokan-form-group, this is breaking the > from continuing after the dokan-child-wrapper.

Comment: @wharfdale Why not just something like this https://jsfiddle.net/x2rcobf7/ ? Is there going to be more childs? And you need red only first 4? I don't get it.